# How to do proxy tunnelling in java signed applet

Tags: java, proxy, applet, httpconnection, http-tunneling

**how to make persistent connections behind proxy in an applet?****

is Using URLConnection will do all the job?

I know what i am asking is very general but i am desperate for any ideas.


Acording to the article in this [link](http://www.idssoftware.com/jdbchttps.html):

> For HTTP requests, the proxy server is
>   able to parse the communication
>   content and exercise a lot more
>   discretion on policing the traffics,
>   including dropping the connection at
>   the appropriate time (a proxy server
>   always assumes HTTP connections are
>   non-persistent).

**is it true? is there a general rule for proxy servers that all http connections are non-persistent?


so does this mean that if one is trying to make a persistent connection through proxy(which doesnt supports socks) can only be done via https connection?**

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: for the customers which are behind isa server.Network manager told me that the unsuccsessfull connections doesnt have the proxy authentication cridentials. What I dont understand is how one connection can have the credentials and the other doesnt have.Only difference is first one is on the same server the second is not.

Comment: Don't you get a stacktrace with a message? I'd like to see that message. It indicates the problem. You say that the applet is signed, but it sounds odd that it can connect back to the same server, but not to another server. That sounds like a security error/exception, and that it isn't signed.

Comment: in the unsuccsessfull connection attemp connection is persistent. but the network manager claims that it doesnt matter for them

Answer (score 0):

Connection refused usually means that there is no service listening on the port you are attempting to connect to. Can you access that address/port from the machine that is running the applet? Is the port open in the firewall on the server?

Comment: Can you connect to it from the machine that is running the applet? Try to connect using a browser, or with e.g. SoapUI

Answer (score 0):

In General, Proxies may not validate persistent connections. You need to drop and reconnect after some short timeout for passing proxy. 
I think the reason of why connection b is failing should be searched within that area (i. e. generaly said: because it is persistent connection).